SAGA Next Generation and QGIS
How can I install/connect SAGA Next Gen in QGIS?
I've tried installing the 'processing_saga_nextgen' plugin in QGIS (version 1.0.0) as below, but it's not working as it should (**).
My setup:

QGIS version : 3.34.7-Prizren - QGIS code revision - 6f7d735c
Qt version 5.15.13
Python version 3.12.4
GDAL/OGR version 3.9.0
PROJ version 9.4.0
EPSG Registry database version v11.004 (2024-02-24)
GEOS version 3.12.2-CAPI-1.18.2
SQLite version 3.45.1
PDAL version 2.6.3
PostgreSQL client version unknown
SpatiaLite version 5.1.0
QWT version 6.2.0
QScintilla2 version 2.14.1
OS version Windows 11 Version 2009

Active Python plugins

crayfish 3.6.0
lizmap 4.3.16
profiletool 4.2.6
QCopycanvas  0.7
qgiscloud 3.9.10
quick_map_services 0.19.34
db_manager 0.1.20
MetaSearch 0.3.6
processing 2.12.99




Hi Spokesman1, wlecome to GIS SE. Don't format your question in bold, this is for titles only - looks like shouting at us... Also give a descripton of your problem, not just post system messages and screenshots. See [tour] for how this site works.

Try adding a description of the error you're experiencing - why / how is it not working ? based on the screen shots it seems to be installed and active in QGIS

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you do everything suggested here for the install? https://qgis-in-mineral-exploration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/how_to/add_saga_next_gen.html
